# Get the order of bytes by value

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have an interesting thought-problem right now, so maybe someone of you could help.

Basically what I have is an array of bytes and need to know the order of each individual item in that array - by value. Oh man, i will just show you a small example, i think that will help better:

```
byte[] array = new byte[4] { 42, 5, 17, 39 }
```

I want to get this as a result

```
4 1 2 3
```

What would be a smart way to do this?

In addition i would like the algorithm to retain the order, if the entries are valued equal. So

```
new byte[4] { 22, 33, 33, 11 }
```

should result in

```
2 3 4 1
```

Comment: Isn't that just sorting the array [1, 2, 3, 4] with the input array as key? Just a good old Array.Sort(one_through_n, input_array)
edit: nevermind, it isn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[4] { 42, 5, 17, 39 };

var results = byteArray.Select((b, i) => new { Value = b, Index = i})
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Value)
                    .Select((p, i) => new { Index = p.Index, SortedPosition = i + 1 })
                    .OrderBy(p => p.Index)
                    .Select(p => p.SortedPosition);
```

Comment: Yeah it misses the +1 for the index, but other than that it works fine :) I will test this in my console app and will give you the answer marked once i have tested it enough!

Comment: @Daniel - still the elements are not emitted in the right order

Comment: I Agree with Daniel the result will be correct once +1 is added to index.

Comment: well how do you relate `results` with the original array then? first element of `results` should be the position of `42`

Comment: @Reed Unfortunatly, it does not work: 2,2,1,3 should result in 1,2,0,3 but results in 2,0,1,3

Comment: @UrbanEsc: It actually reported in the wrong order previously - this will give you the proper answer...

Comment: @UrbanEsc: Did the latest update give you what you want?  (Its working for your examples...)

Answer (score 3):

```
byte[] array = new byte[4] { 42, 5, 17, 39 }
var sorted = array.OrderBy(x=> x);

var result = from b in sorted 
    select (x => array.IndexOf(x) + 1);
```

As noted, this does not handle duplicates.

Comment: `sorted` should be IEnumerable<byte> or var. OrderBy does not return an array.

Comment: +1 from me. @Daniel A. White: This *will* work if the items are not unique: "This method performs a stable sort; that is, if the keys of two elements are equal, the order of the elements is preserved." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: @Andrew: But the IndexOf fails on dupes.

Comment: It also will scale very poorly even for unique values, due to the lookup.

Comment: @Henk: True - though I'd assume he's not doing this on data he's typing manually ;)

Comment: @Henk Holterman I typed this example really quickly in here, so, yeah, its not "prod-ready" code there ;) Anyway would you enlighten me what you mean there?